# Create List of UNIQUE Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Right now I have the following happening:

EAN | Material | Title | Size | Weight

Though depending on the category, one might be added or deleted.

I want to create a seperate list which lists all unique values ever found and saves old ones, which are not in the cell anymore.

Right now I have
`=UNIQUE(transpose(E1:L1))`

This allows me to create a list of all the unique values, though if one gets removed, it doesn't stay.

Here is an example file: [Google Sheets Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ihGqWt_TEYmHKl48BR6AaIc3qufNyBPFalZLEWD35Sg/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is with an extra log sheet and an Apps Script script.

Here is one that I have written and tested in a copy of your sheet:

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var blad1 = ss.getSheetByName('Blad1');
  var editHistory = ss.getSheetByName('editHistory');
  var editRange = blad1.getRange('E1:L1');

  var eRange = e.range;
  var eRow = eRange.getRow();
  var eCol = eRange.getColumn();

  if (eCol >= editRange.getColumn() && eCol <= editRange.getLastColumn() && eRow >= editRange.getRow() && eRow <= editRange.getLastRow() && !eRange.isBlank()) {
    var newVal = eRange.getValue();
    editHistory.appendRow([newVal]);
  }
}
```

This script takes any value that's placed into the edit range (in your case that's `E1:L1`) and appends it to the extra sheet. From this, you can use a `UNIQUE()` formula that points to the list in this sheet in order to get a full unique history of all the entered values.

[image: ex]
[image: ex2]

Comment: These type of phrases (Please let me know if you have any issues with this, or would like me to explain anything) are [better avoided](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-like-greetings-signatures-thanks-etc-when-editin). SO is considered  similar to a wikipedia, where answers are more for external viewers than for a specific asker.

Comment: @TheMaster I end nearly all of my answers with that line. I understand where you're coming from, but the post you linked also refers to fluff in questions, not answers. That line, in my opinion, is not fluff and is there as a way to let the user know that I may have made a mistake, and/or am free to discuss my response. I have found that adding this line at the end has a much higher chance of getting a user response when there is an issue and being able to discuss it, than when the line is not added and my answer is often disregarded until one that actually works is posted.

Comment: Maybe this is a better link: ["Is it acceptable to put "if you have any questions or something wasn't right just let me know" in my answers?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412759/is-it-acceptable-to-put-if-you-have-any-questions-or-something-wasnt-right-jus?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your explanation, though, when putting it in Apps script, it gives an error: " 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Save.gs:7"

Comment: @Scraper2022 this script will automatically run whenever you edit the sheet. Don't worry about running it manually. If you change a value in the range of `E1:L1`, the script will log it in the editHistory sheet. You will get this error if you run the script from the editor, as `e` (the variable that defines the edit event) would be undefined (because no edit actually happened)

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 I got the edithistory unique values working, amazing. Though due to probably the way I am importing something, it only takes the value from 1 column and not all of them.

The Values are now in Row 2, starting from F.

Comment: @Scraper2022 in the code there is a variable called `editRange`. Within that variable, you can change the specified range to whatever you need it to be. It is currently set to `E1:L1`, it would just need to remain in the same row for the current script to still work with it (ie `F2:J2`)

Answer (score 0):

#### Unique

```
function unique() {
  Logger.log([...new Set(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E1:L1").getValues().flat())]);
}
```